# send xml data from j2me app to remote server

Tags: php, xml, java-me

I have a J2ME application - which generates XML data (from an object) and needs to get it sent across to a remote server/machine. How do I get this xml or the object through to the remote server please? Thanks. Just in case it might help, the receiving application on the remote server is PHP powered. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using HttpConnection to POST data to the server where you'd easily be able to access it in PHP using $_POST. I found a sample (not tested) entitled "HTTP POST from a J2ME midlet" http://codetrips.blogspot.com/2007/04/http-post-from-j2me-midlet.html which should help.